# How to update text content dynamically from a web server depending on the iOS app language

Tags: ios

How to update text content dynamically from a web server depending on the ios app language.  I am building an ios application and I want to update the text data of the app depending on the language that each iPhone user has selected.

Comment: What have you tried?  It's unclear what you're asking.  A different web page for each language?  A different RESTful call for each language?  Sending a language parameter as part of the URL? Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

As a first approach I would recommend something like having translations stored in your web server. Then make the client set the language header based on the user's locale, and make the server respond with the corresponding language based on that request's header. Both things are standard and implementing them should be pretty straightforward.

I know it is very wide answer, but it is difficult to propose something more accurately if you don't provide any further details.

Comment: I'd like to add a reference to [`[NSLocale currentLocale]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale). It may help solve the problem.